# UWP GridView drag drop not working

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I am moving my windows 8.1 app to Windows 10 UWP. I am able to port it fine. But the drag drop functionality with `GridView` / `ListView` seems to be not working.

I have got the `CanDragItems="True"` set on `GridView` and `AllowDrop="True"` on the target as specified in the documentation. This was working fine on windows 8.1 but not with Windows 10 UWP. I cant find any documentation related to this for any specific setting to be added for Window 10 UWP to enable this functionality. When I drag items from the view, it shows restricted icon while I drag the item.

Can someone advice how to fix this issue?

regards

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://our.componentone.com/2015/10/11/how-to-upgrade-extended-gridview-from-winrt-to-universal-windows-platform-uwp/) page.

Comment: Have you tried the official [Drag and drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) ? This may helps you. And if you still have this issue, please share your code so that we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for the sample , I have now managed to make the drag drop work. It required handling of drag drop events as described in sample.